# phonegap hypride online and offline app

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm developing a Sencha-touch app which I'm packaging with Phonegap. To make developing easier, I only use Phonegap as shell to load my online website. This all works fine and I don't need to build and distribute the app every time something changes. I only need to update my online website.

Except now I want to use some PhoneGap events (resume, deviceready etc). In order to get these events working I need to include the gordova.js file in the index.html.

My problem is that the index.html is on my server and not in the Phonegap www folder. So when I try to include gordova.js in the index.html like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

The application search the cordova.js on my webserver and can't find the file. I know I could place the cordova.js file on my server, but the cordova.js file difference for each platform and then I don't know which (platform) cordova file I need to load.

Is there a way to include offline files (in the Phonegap www folder) in my online loaded index.html file? Or do you've other suggestions?

Thanks Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Place **index.html** file in the `assets\www` directory and let it be the starting point of your application.
In the **index.html** file which will be located in the `assets\www` directory you need to add the following code in the **head** tag. The window.location will redirect to your website URL.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use the Codova API
     window.location="http://your.website/index.html"; }
</script>
```

You need to enable CORS. To enable CORS on the client follow the below steps.
Tell Cordova that it is safe to load your website in the **config.xml** properties (you can remove the subdomains part if you don't have any)

```
<access origin="http://your.website" subdomains="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I still nog able to use the Cordova api inside 'http://your.website' because all Cordova api is attached to the window object (window.cordova) and is removed when I change the window.location.

Comment: Another alternative would be to use AJAX. This will keep the the first page loaded and subsequent request will manipulate the DOM accordingly. This may require refactoring of your website to support AJAX calls from your APP.

Comment: That's a good solution. For now the refactoring is to much work. I will serve the cordova.js from the webserver (first checking the correct target platform)